# How to switch between Activities using the same Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using an Action Bar, with Fragments. I want to switch Activity on Action-Item click event.

I make an Intent Another Activity, on click event. But when another Activity gets invoked, it comes with a **new screen**. While I am using the same `layout.xml` in setcontentView in both of the Activities.

I want to switch Activity, while staying on the same screen.

Since I have used Fragments programmatically, replace fragment on switching Activity.

Comment: are you adding fragments to FragmentActivity??

Comment: check https://github.com/rathodchintan/Fragment-Back-Stack

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you have **1** Activity and just replace the Fragments inside it?

Comment: Why are you using two activities then....only use FragmentActivity and replace fragment there...

Comment: you mean complete application put into single Activity, it is not feasible . i have 11K LOC in a Activity , and having two Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide same layout for two activities then also it will shows like new screen. Because if you start new activity the new instance of the activity will be created and new screen will come and if any default activity transition animation is there that will be applied to the new activity.

Comment: i need to apply some animation to hide jumping new screen.

Comment: but Thanks , for your effort

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
if (getActivity() instanceof YourActivity){
// do something
}else{
//do something else 
}
```